# Efficiently concatenate/append dataframe in a for loop to get a single big dataframe using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using a logic- I am reading multiple PDF files which are having certain highlighted portions(presume that these are tables).

After pushing them to a list, I am saving them to a dataframe.
Here's the logic for the same

```
    try:
        filepath = [file for file in glob.glob("Folder/*.pdf")]
        for file in filepath:
            doc = fitz.open(file)
            print(file)

            highlights = []
            for page in doc:
                highlights += handle_page(page)

            #print(highlights)
            highlights_alt = highlights[0].split(',')
            df = pd.DataFrame(highlights_alt, columns=['Security Name'])
            #print(df.columns.tolist())
            df[['Security Name', 'Weights']] = df['Security Name'].str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True)
            df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
            print(df.head())
            print(df.shape)
    except IndexError:
        print('file {} is not highlighted'.format(file))
```

Using this logic I get the dataframes however if the folder has 5 PDFs then this logic creates 5 different dataframes. Something like this.

```
Folder\z.pdf
Security Name Weights
0     UTILITIES   (5.96
1           %*)    None
(2, 2)

Folder\y.pdf
 Security Name Weights
0  Quantity/ Market Value % of Net Investments Cu...   1.125
1                                                  %      01
2                                                /07    None
3                                              /2027    None
4                                                EUR     230
(192, 2)

Folder\x.pdf
Security Name Weights
0                  Holding    £740
1                      000    None
2   Leeds Building Society    3.75
3               % variable      25
4                       /4    None
(526, 2)
```

However I want a single dataframe with the above records in them making their shape as `(720,2)` something like

```
Security Name Weights
0                  Holding    £740
1                      000    None
2   Leeds Building Society    3.75
3               % variable      25
4                       /4    None
.
.
720  xyz                      3.33
(720, 2)
```

I tried using pandas's `concat & append` but have been unsuccessful so far. Please let me know an efficient way of doing it since, the PDFs in future would be more than 1000s.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way is to use `pd.concat`:

```py
big_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, axis=0)
```

If this creates an error it would be helpful to know what the error is.

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: Make sure `list_of_dfs` is indeed a list, the error says it's a dataframe.

Comment: i used ```final_df = pd.concat([df], axis=0)``` it still gave the same output it gave in my question

Comment: That's odd, but hard to debug remotely.

Comment: you could probably take a look at the code which I've written. will creating the dataframe before for loop help here? I've created it in the loop itself

Comment: Yes, but based on that code I would expect pd.concat to work... so not sure what's going on.

Comment: its just a single df maybe because of that It didn't ??

Comment: Nope, I just tried on a single df and it works...

Comment: interesting. it would be better if you could paste your code here, i have to see where I am going wrong